# angular filter in a mouse event variable

Tags: html, angularjs, json, filter, mouseevent

Is there a way place a filter in a variable that is being changed on mouse events?

For example if I have `ng-mouseover="text = 'Create a new item in this list'"` and I would like to replace it with a filter that reads a translation from a JSON file: `ng-mouseover="text = '{{'create_new'|translate}}'"`

But this is not acceptable in angular. Is it syntactically wrong or it's simply not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it like that:

`ng-mouseover ="item.showText = true"`

`ng-moseleave = "item.showText=false"`

than you can set html-css class on the your item and set its ng-show attribute like:

`ng-show="item.showText"`

example:

```
 <label class=".." ng-Model="item" ng-mouseover ="item.showText = true" ng-moseleave = "item.showText=false"> {{item.text}} </label>
```

`<span ng-show="item.showText">{{'create_new' | translate }}</span>`

This is not exactly solution, this is only idea for you. As I said you can solve this with css-html support.